# Replace < and > in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to replace "<" and ">" in jquery in order to display to human being `<div>` for example.
I'd like it to do it after initialisation.
Any idea?

```
var el = $("#mydiv").clone();
el.text().replace(new RegExp("<", 'g'), "&lt;");
el.html().replace(new RegExp(">", 'g'), "&gt;");
$("mydiv").after(el);
```

And you think it is possible to do the same from a JS function?

```
<script>
function myFunction(){
console.log("yeah")}
</script>
```

into=>

```
<div>
function myFunction(){
console.log("yeah")}
</div>
```

Comment: You wrote "<" two times instead of "<" and ">" in your code

Comment: You also need to set the result of `replace()` to a variable.

Comment: should this question be closed as a typo?

Comment: Replacing `<>` after the page is rendered isn't going to protect you from XSS attacks.  have you considered fixing it in the source before the page is sent to the client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier to call `.html()` on your element and save it to `.text()`;

```js
var el = $("#mydiv").clone();
$(el).text($(el).html());
$("#mydiv").after(el);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mydiv">I'm a <span style="color:red">test</span></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the content with the string return by **[`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)** method or use **[`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/)** method with a callback function.

```
var el = $("#mydiv").clone();  

el.html(function(i,v){ 
   return v.replace(/</g, "&gt;").replace(/>/g, "&lt;");
});

$("mydiv").after(el);
```